# Why am I getting the wrong document root?

Tags: apache, zend-framework, virtualhost

I am working through this tutorial- https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/

In trying to get it setup on an Apache local server I have used this code-

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName zf-tutorial.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/skeleton-application/public
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
<Directory /var/www/html/skeleton-application/public>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try and go to http://zf-tutorial.localhost I see a directory listing that looks like this-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xTRM.jpg

This url- http://zf-tutorial.localhost/skeleton-application/public/ actually displays the correct index.php file.

How do I get http://zf-tutorial.localhost to display the index.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to have everything sorted and connected well. I care about directory names to match configuration files and names so I will leave you here how I would do that.

1. Install your aplication in `/var/www/zf-tutorial.localhost`
2. `cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`
3. `sudo cp 000-default.conf zf-tutorial.localhost.conf`
4. Open that file and change `ServerName` to `zf-tutorial.localhost`
5. Change `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www/zf-tutorial.localhost/public`
6. You can add additional parameters/settings like `SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"`
7. You can change access log and error log for easier debugging and troubleshooting. For me it would be `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/zf-tutorial.localhost.access.log` and `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/zf-tutorial.localhost.error.log`
8. Save and close
9. `sudo a2ensite zf-tutorial.localhost.conf`
10. `sudo service apache2 reload`

Here you should be ready to go. With this, you don't need that separate VirtualHost rule up there since you set it now in separated configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove Apache's default virtual host:

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

and reload the web server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: When I did that it stopped loading all together. Any other ideas?